# Ajax Get Request with JQuery Error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, get

I'm trying to call a php script with a get request and using the data theaddress however the results are showing me the source of the page im calling.

The page im calling is [here](http://pear.coreyjansen.com/r10database/checkSystem/ManorWPG.php?theaddress=131%20ALFRED%20AVE)
Here is my ajax function that will get this page

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var address = document.getElementById("address");

     $.ajax({
      url: '/r10database/checkSystem/ManorWPG.php',
      type: 'GET',
      data: 'theaddress='+address.value,
      cache: false,
      success: function(output) 
      {
          alert('success, server says '+output);
      }, error: function()
      {
        alert('Something went wrong, saving system failed');
      }
   });



    });
```

Comment: Does setting `dataType: 'xml'` in the ajax() call help?

Comment: What do you mean by "the source of the page [you are] calling?" It shows you the source of `/r10database/checkSystem/ManorWPG.php?theaddress=FOO` or the source of something else? If the former, isn't that what you wanted it to do?

Comment: it normally happens when there is something wrong in php page that has been called

Comment: I tried changing the datatype to xml and it returned an error alert('Something went wrong, saving system failed')

Comment: The page http://pear.coreyjansen.com/r10database/checkSystem/ManorWPG.php?theaddress=131%20ALFRED%20AVE works fine when I call it manually

Comment: This is what ajax does, it gets the page / output of file ?

Comment: That page has ajax and google maps (and errors), what are you expecting when you're getting it with ajax ?

Comment: I dont want it to show anything all I want it to do is call the page so it can execute the script if that makes sense. The only reason I have the output is so I can try and debug @adeneo

Comment: The page I am calling determines what polygon the address is in then uses ajax to call another php sript which saves the polygon into mysql. @adeneo

Comment: I don't think that's going to work, you can't call a page with ajax and expect that page to do ajax requests and cough up dynamic data before it's returned to the initial ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var address = document.getElementById("address");

 $.ajax({
  url: '/r10database/checkSystem/ManorWPG.php',
  type: 'GET',
  data: 'theaddress='+address.value,
  cache: false,
  success: function(output) 
  {
      alert('success, server says '+output);
  }, error: function(error)
  {
    alert (error); // this is the change from the question
  }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the dataType as json with a curly brace

```
data: {theaddress:address.value},
dataType:'json',
success: function(output) 
{
    alert('success, server says '+output);
}, error: function(xhr)
{
   alert (xhr.status);
}
```

and get the data in ManorWPG.php as **$_GET['theaddress']**

** share the xhr.status if failed.